# I'm getting duplicate outputs in powershell script

Tags: powershell, filesystems, acl

I am trying to display information from foders, subfolders, and files over an entire filesystem. It seems to be working fine other than I keep getting multiples results for each file. When I run this script, the resulting csv shows three rows for each file, containing the same data. (making my file much larger than I want it to be)

```
$OutFile = "C:\Owners.csv"
$Header = "Folder Path,FileName,LastAccessTime,Owner"
Del $OutFile
Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $OutFile 
$RootPath = "S:\0411" 
$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse 
     foreach ($Folder in $Folders){
        $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access  }
        Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){
        $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $Folder.name + "," + $Folder.LastAccessTime     + "," + ((Get-ACL $Folder.FullName).Owner)
     $arr += $obj
        Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $OutFile
        }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing multiple results because each file/folder has multiple ACL's associated with it.

You're taking each file/folder and then looping it through and getting the ACL's for each.

Modify your line for $OutInfo to the following to see what I mean:

```
$OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $Folder.name + "," + $Folder.LastAccessTime     + "," + ((Get-ACL $Folder.FullName).Owner) + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + "," + $ACL.FileSystemRights
```

Edit: Typo

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else, skip to the better solution down further. This first bit explains the answer to your question, but there's a better way to do things.

You're getting dupes because for each file/folder you are getting the ACLs, and then for each ACL you are looping through the access list. So let's say...

Folder: C:\Temp
Owner: BUILTIN\Administrators
Access List:

- BUILTIN\Administrators
- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users

So for that folder you are looping through the Access list, which has 3 entries. For each entry you are outputting a line into your CSV file.

**Better Solution:**

Ok, you are manually building a CSV file, and that's just crazy. Let's do this easier:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Owners.csv"
$RootPath = "S:\0411" 
$Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse 
$Folders | Select FullName,Name,LastAccessTime,@{l='Owner';e={Get-ACL $_.FullName | Select -ExpandProperty Owner}} | Export-CSV $OutFile -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$OutFile = "C:\Owners.csv"
$RootPath = "S:\0411" 
Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,Name,LastAccessTime,
    @{n='Owner';e={(get-acl $_.FullName).owner}} | Export-CSV $OutFile
```

Note that Get-ChildItem will get all folders and files, not just folders. Because you named your variable $folders, I suspect you only want containers? If so, use the -ad switch:

```
$OutFile = "C:\Owners.csv"
$RootPath = "S:\0411" 
Get-ChildItem $RootPath -ad -Recurse | Select-Object FullName,Name,LastAccessTime,
        @{n='Owner';e={(get-acl $_.FullName).owner}} | Export-CSV $OutFile
```

A couple of recommendations:
1) Don't use aliases in your scripts. They're good for use in the console, not so much if anyone else needs to read it. e.g., 'dir' for Get-ChildItem, 'del' for Remove-Item.
2) Learn to use Select-Object and Export-CSV if you're looking for CSV output.
3) Export-CSV will overwrite any existing file, so no need to delete it first.